# Texture painting on a 3D model

Tags: opengl, textures, paint, projection, brush

I know that there are a couple of similar questions here already but the answers don't really help with what I'm trying to achieve. As the title suggests, I wish to project a texture onto a 3D model (to its UV-mapped texture to be exact) in OpenGL. The best example of this has been shown in this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pT4bx4J4NQQ

In the comments, the author mentions that he's "projecting each pixel of the gun that the brush is over back to UV space and update the original texture". I assume that he's doing this by rendering an additional UV pass that allows him to replace the visible pixels with the ones from the brush texture. As usual, easier said than done: the main problem is that when we zoom out from our model and start projecting, not all of the model's UV's will be seen in screen space and therefore zooming back in should reveal "holes" (where the model's UVs were too small to render in screen space).

**So my question is** - how can I avoid these holes when painting from a distance? Projection mapping isn't the answer here because it would affect all faces the brush is over, even ones behind the visible surface. Super sampling won't handle extreme situations either and will be slow as hell.

I also doubt that he's going through all of the model's texture's pixels to determine if they are located below the brush as increasing its size or creating paint strokes would slow things down significantly.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? I'm stuck pretty much at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

What the implementer of the program shown in the video probably did was drawing the model in an additional off-screen pass with the texture ST coordinates in an off-screen pass. Now years ago there was a way to "pick" objects by using a special rendering mode (selection mode) – don't use it, it's super slow and inefficient. But one of the essential steps of selection mode picking is, that a special "pick" matrix is multiplied on top of the projection and modelview matrices that will kind of "zoom" the transformation volume to just what's below the selection rectangle. If you combine that additional transformation with a ST coordinate rendering pass into a sufficiently high resolution buffer (call this the texture geometry buffer).

Now comes the tricky part: Remember that texturing is effectively a mapping from ST space to proj(modelview(XYZW)) (hence the term texture mapping). What you effectively want is an inverse mapping. And if you don't care about the local curvature you can do this by simply *swapping* the coordinates passed into your "mapping" machine. So if you put proj(modelview(XYZW)) into where ST would go and vice versa it gives you an inverse mapping. Do this with your decal as texture and the texture geometry buffer you've reversed the texture mapping and are drawing the decal into your model's texture space. So set your model texture as color attachment for the FBO in which you do the reversed drawing and use the decal as texture to draw and there you go.

> So my question is - how can I avoid these holes when painting from a distance?

By interpolating over it. And this happens for free if your intermediary buffers are sufficient high resolution. Note that I'm not the author of the program shown in the video you linked. But I once *did* write such a program, though I misplaced its sources. It's not too difficult to do, and you can usually find a function like this in every major 3D modelling package. There's little use for having a crude techdemo around for doing this, if properly tools are around.